# Is there a language that breaks out of conditional statements as soon as they become false?

Tags: programming-languages

I thought that I had come across this before, but I can't remember when or what language it was.
Basically if I have the following in C#:

```
someCondition = true
if(someCondition)
{
    // Do Something
    if(anotherCond) {
        someCondition = false;
        continue;
    }
    // Do Something Else
}
```

In C# this will break out of the body of the if statement when `someCondition` changes, meaning that `//DO Something Else` only gets processed if `someCondition` doesn't change...

Is there a language that will do the interior if statement checking/continue automatically i.e. be able to write:

```
someCondition = true
if(someCondition)
{
    // Do Something
    if(anotherCond){
        someCondition = false;
    }
    // Do Something Else
}
```

with the same behaviors as the previous? ***Obviously there are multiple ways to get this behavior in every language conceivable***, what I am interested in is if there is a language that  by design has this functionality.

Edit: Reduced the examples so hopefully people can see what is happening, when someCondition changes (i.e. the condition that the if statement relied on to begin, we should break out of the remaining if statement. **I am not looking for a way to do this in C#, or any particular language, but for a language that does this automatically.**

Comment: If I get you right, you want the language to somehow monitor the `truth` variable and exit the corresponding `if` statement if the value changes?

Comment: Doubtful, and if there is, I'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: I find this question unclear. In the second example `if (cond)` is missing. So how could this ever behave the same? Note: I did not downvote.

Comment: @Henrik , the point of the second example is that the 'if(cond)' is missing, I was looking for a language that would be able to continue based on the changed conditional

Comment: @akonsu, care to explain where I am not making sense?

Comment: to check something automatically you will need to know what to check. in the pseudo code you omitted the 'cond', so it is unclear to me how you want to communicate to the compiler what to check? in addition, suppose the compiler knows what to check, the question is what statement does it need to break out of?

Comment: @akonsu The cond isn't important, it is just there to show that something happened and the value of truth changed, which caused a continue to skip the rest of the conditional statement, I'm looking for a programming language that does this automatically

Comment: I understand I think. I do not know of any such language.

Comment: @NominSim I think you should edit your second code sample to still include the `if(cond)`, so the only thing different would be the missing `continue`. That seems to be what's confusing people.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks, that's a good idea, I didn't want to have it in the original statement either, but I thought it would have confused people more if I just had a continue in the middle of the statement

Comment: suppose that there is no while loop around the if statement. can you describe the semantics that you are looking for?

Comment: @akonsu I edited the original question to take out the while loop, it wasn't necessarily important to the question, but was used to show an example of why it might be needed, hopefully the semantics are more clear now; simply that if you enter a conditional statement, then if the condition changes the language, not the program, decides to exit the statement at that point

Comment: If there is any language that implements such crap, it must be INTERCAL.

Comment: @Ingo, how is that "crap"? I can see where it might not be a general case for most programs, but it is definitely necessary in certain cases

Comment: @NominSim - In essence you want a GOTO that is automatically happening without the need to even write it down? Does it not occur to you that this is worse than "COME FROM"?

Comment: @Ingo, not sure that a goto that happens automatically is what I am looking for, just that when a conditional statement is entered it bails out when the condition is false...this happens in programming all of the time, not sure why the behavior is "crap"

Comment: @NominSim - no, when you *enter* the block (in your example), the the condition is true, if it is not, then the block is not entered. So far so good. But you want to leave in the middle of the block when the value of the condition changed in-between. Or did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: @Ingo No you understood correctly, but I don't get how this behavior is "Crap" to you, there are millions of programs that run based on a condition, and stop some process when that condition is not met anymore.

Comment: +NonimSim - true, but this is then made explicit by a while-loop or, more general, by an explicit check, so that one who reads that program knows exactly when the check is done.

Comment: @Ingo ...yeah, I was looking for a situation when the programming language explicitly checks for a change while in a conditional statement...

Comment: I'll write an answer to make my standpoint clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property in C# that throws an exception on any condition you set, aka `truth=true`.  The exception will break out of the loop to wherever you have your catch.

An example in C#:

```
public class MyException : Exception { }

public bool truth
{
    get { return _truth; }
    set
    {
        _truth = value;
        if(value)
            throw new MyException();
     }
}
bool _truth;
```

Comment: Never use exceptions for flow control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simulate what you want in C# like so:

```
void ExecuteWhile( Func<bool> condition, 
    IEnumerable<Action> executeWhileTrue, 
    IEnumerable<Action> executeWhileFalse)
{
    if (condition())
    {
         foreach (Action action in executeWhileTrue)
         {
             action();
             if (!condition())
                 return;
         }
    }
    else
    {
         foreach (Action action in executeWhileFalse)
         {
             action();
             if (condition())
                 return;
         }
    }
}
```

and then use it as such:

```
truth = true;
while (true) // loop forever
{
    ExecuteWhile( () => truth,
        new List<Action> { () => { /* do something that might set truth to false*/},
                           () => { /* do something else*/}},
        new List<Action> { () => { /* do something that might set truth to true*/},
                           () => { /* do something else*/}});
}
```

And to answer your question: no, I don't think there is a language with this as a build-in feature.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, the following is wanted:

```
if (cond) {
    A;
    B;
    C;
}
```

shall behave as if written thus:

```
if (cond) {
   A;
   if (cond) {
       B;
       if (cond) {
           C
       }
   }
}
```

IMHO, this would be a silly feature, unlikely to be implemented in any language except maybe in INTERCAL.
Why do I think that?

Well, suppose someone wants to refactor the code and moves `B;C` to a subroutine.

```
if (cond) {
    A;
    BC();
}

subroutine BC() { B;C }
```

The block - according to our feature - will mean as before:

```
if (cond) {
    A;
    if (cond) BC();
}
```

But what about our subroutine? The language designer has 2 choices here:

- Treat the call `BC()` as atomic, i.e. in the subroutine, the
  condition `cond` is not checked before statement `C`. This would mean
  such a simple refactoring would change the meaning of the program
  **drastically**.
- Somehow pass the information that every statement must be guarded
  with `cond` to the subroutine so that the behaviour of our block remains
  unchanged. This, of course, leads to the silly situation that the
  behaviour of any subroutine would depend upon the context it was
  called in. A subroutine with n atomic statements would have n possible ways to behave ***even if*** it had no arguments and would not use non local mutable state explicitely, depending on how many of the statements would be actually executed. (Note that nowadays the trend is to minimize the most often harmful effects of shared non-local state. OO languages do it with encapsulation, FP languages by banning mutable state altogether.)

In any case, no matter how the language designer decides, we would have a feature that is the direct contradiction of the principle of the least surprise. It is clear that programs in such a language would be utterly hard to maintain.

Comment: The behavior isn't necessarily as you stated, it would operate more like an event for a property change, i.e. if cond changes then the event is processed, with the result of the event being the exit of the conditional statement. So if we had a routine BC() {B;C} as you suggest, it would operate the same way. The interior of the conditional statement can at any time be broken by the change of the cond

Comment: +NominSim - this is what I described in the 2nd choice. It menas that, if we see `subroutine x { print 'a'; print 'b'; }` we cannot say: This subroutine prints "ab". Rather, we have to say: Maybe it prints "a" or maybe "ab", depending on where it was called.

Comment: Ah I see, so what is the issue with this? I can see that being a useful behavior in an albeit specific programming language

Comment: +NominSim In my opinion, this has tremedous implications on maintainability of the code. You just never know what some code really does *unless* you look at the call site (which is probably another subroutine, so you start over looking at their call site, and so forth ...). Mind you, if you think you like this, I have no problems with it. I just told you my opinion that most people will not like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you broke you big bunch if/else statements into succinct little methods which tested each little piece of the puzzle, you could rely on the compilers short circuit boolean evaluation

I'm not sure if that helps as your example is a big vague. You don't say if you're doing any processing or if it's just a bunch of checks. Either way, breaking your code into smaller methods may help you out.

Comment: i'm curious why this answer got downvoted. is breaking logic into smaller more manageable chunks not a good idea any more?!

Comment: I wanted a language that has the behavior specified built in, breaking it into smaller more manageable chunks is the opposite direction...

Comment: okay, then the short answer is that isn't a language feature of C#. However if you were to break you checks into smaller more specific checks then you could either put them into a big if statement and rely on short circuit boolean evaluation, or if you wanted to be able to add more check at runtime, put them into a list and do your "while (truth)" loop checking each element in the list (which would set the value of "truth" by returning a boolean.

Comment: ...I am aware that it is not a language feature of C#, which should seem obvious in the question "Is there a language..."

Comment: fine. perhaps you should remove the C# tag then.

Comment: my bad, i'm not sure why I mentioned C# in my comment. i didn't in my answer, which could apply to any language which uses short circuit boolean evaluation. But, to my knowledge there is no such feature in any of the languages I use. But, I don't know all the features of all the languages I use. If there were such a feature I would hope it'd be very obvious what was going on as it's not a familiar pattern to most programmers. It strikes me that it could lead to confusion when reading the code if it weren't very obvious. Possibly a specific keyboard rather a variant on a loop.

Comment: @AntonyScott No problem, my question apparently wasn't very clear from the beginning. I could have sworn though that I had encountered this behavior before(the only reason I remember was that it was very annoying to debug my program while I didn't realize that it happened)

Comment: lol, that kind of backs up what I said about making it obvious!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a do..while loop:

```
        do
        {

        } while (truth == true);
```

thats if i've understood correctly!

Comment: That would still require the continue to get the same behavior, there is no answer in C#, I am looking for a language that does it automatically...

Answer (score -1):

You say while true... but while what is true. I would think your loop will run infinitely regardless of the language used. Assuming true will be a real condition... I would say just set the exit condition in one of the if blocks. You question is a bit hard to understand. Also the continue is unnecessary.